# Data-structural bootstrapping examples?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, functional-programming, bootstrapping

I recently read Okasaki and Brodal's paper ["Optimal Purely Functional Priority Queues,"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.6733&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which describes a fast priority queue based on data-structural bootstrapping, in which a simple and inefficient data structure is used to construct a robust and efficient structure.  This seems like a really beautiful theoretical idea, but so far the only example I know of is the one from this paper.

Does anyone have any other examples of data-structural bootstrapping that would be a good starting point for further reading on the subject?

Comment: +1 for a great question.  The paper, while interesting, is rather long.  It might be a good idea to show an example of data-structural bootstrapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Chris Okasaki's thesis](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) has a whole chapter on data-structural bootstrapping, including some other examples and references to papers with even more.

Comment: If you're interested in his thesis you might consider buying his book, of the same name, which is based on the thesis.